# Drupal 7 javascript file is not accepting

Tags: drupal-7

I have my custom js file ,I am working on zen subtheme and  I also included my custom javascript file into .info file also but its not working. Can any one please help me?

Comment: try to Flush all cache

Comment: Thanku for your reply,..yes i did it many tomes, even i tried to include my file through `<script>` also but unable to understand the problem

Comment: np mate ^_^, 

if you check firebug, are you see any error on console section ?
also, others likes style.css are include truth ?

if no error, please check the subtheme.info and view here how you include script ... 

after this clear cache

Comment: Thanku so much @Anis hikmat abu-hmiad , In fire bug it was showing error on `$` sign in javascript , i replaced it with `jQuery` , now it is perfectly working :)

Comment: (Y) Yup, Welcome mate ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be come from much of cases, to resolve it you can check these general cases:

1) Flush all cache

2) check firebug is file include or not

3) if file exists check console error (may be is error when declare jQuery library or any js lib error) In your case, this is problem  ^_^

4) if file not exists check you are declare sub theme correctly, if yes check a file include name & extensions, and keep on mind thre is no semicolons before active file ( semicolons used for comment line in .info)

Good Luck

Comment: Yeah @Anis hikmat abu-hmiad, I will remember these points..:)